# Runtime exec method with arguments does not run bash script in Java

Tags: java, bash

I have 2 scenarios below. One where I use the   Runtime.getRuntime().exec method with arguments this does not seems to work I get the error while running the bash script.

However if i use the exec method without passing any values to the exec parameters it works.

```
String cfenv_location="bash /root/.cfenv/environments/ussouth_ys1/bin/cf ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{cfenv_location, "create-service", servicename, planname, appname.replaceAll(" ", "-")});
```

Error:

```
exception happened - here's what I know:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash /root/.cfenv/environments/ussouth_ys1/bin/cf": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
        at JavaRunCommand.cfCreateService(JavaRunCommand.java:111)
        at JavaRunCommand.main(JavaRunCommand.java:359)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
        ... 4 more
```

Works

```
String cfenv_location="bash /root/.cfenv/environments/ussouth_ys1/bin/cf ";
String command = cfenv_location+"login -a "+urllocation+ " -u "+username+ " -p "+password+ " -o "+org+" -s "+space;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the trailing space in first example ? Or even better I'd suggest to have `bash` as command and the rest as parameters...

Comment: I did try that but that does not seem to solve the problem. I get the same error

Comment: You tried also the second option?

Comment: In my experience, I have always found that creating a bash script file from java, writing all the commands and then using exec() to run the bash script works the best.

Comment: Did you mean something like this Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", cfenv_location ,"create-service", servicename, planname, appname.replaceAll(" ", "-")});   ? I tried it but get the same error

Comment: Yes, exactly that, and you removed starting "bash " from the `cfenv_location` variable, right? Please update the question with all you tried (and error messages), to prevent others to ask the same...

Comment: Yea i had removed the bash from the string but damn the same thing

Comment: At least exception message should be different, but while this is not [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) I cannot help further...

Comment: @Betlista that did indeed work... For some reason it was still using the old class file even after i recompiled it. I just delete the class file and regenerated works fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ShekharSuman: come on, title is not for tracking state!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message:

```
Cannot run program "bash /root/.cfenv/environments/ussouth_ys1/bin/cf"
```

shows, that this String is interpreted as a command instead of command and argument (separated with space character).

The proper way is to split the string and call it as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", cfenv_location, ...
```

where cfenv_location is without starting `"base "` part...